# Как записать в файл полученные данные python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
i = type(int(input("Press Number")))

while i <= 10:
    print(i)
    i += 1

with open('test.as', 'w') as f:
    pass
g = open('test.as', 'a')
g.write(i)
g.close()
```

Хочу чтобы то что выйдет в цикле while записалось в файл. Но в итоге получаю ошибку

```
line 10, in <module>
    while i <= 10:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'
```

Помогите решить. Как можно то что выйдет в цикле да и вообще в том что создаётся записывать в файл?

Answer (score 2):

Читайте, пожалуйста, внимательно ошибки. А еще читайте внимательно собственный код.

Ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к записи в файл, а вот с операцией сравнения - беда.

`input("Press Number")` - введенная строчка

`int` - преобразование строки в число (если ввести буквы, то будет ошибка)

А `type` - получение типа данных из значения. Здесь это вообще ни к месту.

Оставьте:
`i = int(input("Press Number"))`

А по поводу записи в файл. Задавать здесь вопрос, совершенно не обязательно. [В интернете слишком много мест, где ответ уже дан](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=python%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8&clid=1955453&win=438&&lr=65), дублировать это как-то избыточно.

```
with open('test.as', 'w') as f:
    pass
```

Эта конструкция означает:

- открыть файл на запись (или создать)
- ничего не сделать
- закрыть файл

Следующая операция успешно создаст файл, если его не было. И лучше использовать `with` везде.